# springboot import classes from one project to another

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

my scheme is as follows

```
-project1 (springboot maven Initializr)
  -model
  -service
  -controller
  -properties(mongodb)
-project2 (springboot maven Initializr)
  -controller (import project1 service)
```

I already added it to dependencies and I call the service of my project1 as follows:

```
import com.example.project1.service.Document_service;
```

I don't have any typing error in my project2, but when I run project2 I have the error:

```
com/example/project2/controller/project2_controller.java:[11,33] package com.example.project1.service 
does not exist
symbol:   class Document_service
location: class com.example.project2.controller.project2_controller
-> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

I need help to run the service1 project on my project2, how can I do it?

Comment: have u add maven dependency to project1 in project2? I think the issue is in there

Comment: @Daniel have you added project1 as subproject? projects need to coordinate with each other either by adding as a jar of prokect1 or add project1 a subproject in project2.

Comment: @ Nitesh Sharma, @ Erwin thanks for the information, could you post your answers with codes? It would be better because I am lost in the settings, I am a novice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I've got your question right, you've made a dependency of one spring boot project on another.

This is, in general, a wrong approach and should not be done, because spring boot artifact is not really a JAR, it has an extension "jar" but doesn't have a structure of jar and hence can't be used by java itself in runtime or a build tool as a dependency (its a very special setup with custom classloader developed by spring boot team, with all the internal dependencies baked into `BOOT-INF/lib` folder).

In terms of resolution, consider introducing a module with all the relevant code but so that it won't be a spring boot service by itself - just a regular JAR.

Then `project1` and `project2` could both add this "common" module as a dependency and this should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clone this project [**Clef Workflow**](https://github.com/Quee-io/clef-workflow). And see my architecture. 
I do my best to do it.

Comment: I hope that will help you. @DanielR.Anccasi

Answer (score 0):

try adding in project2 the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.example.project1", "com.example.project2" })
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer, but I keep getting the same error.